# Large Data Sets for Big Data Analytics

Tags: hadoop, google-analytics, dataset, bigdata

Folks, I am looking for some Data sets, with huge volume of data at least 5gb of data, which is publicly available, **something like Traffic, insurance, weather,forum, hospital etc.** to perform some big data analytic. I googled but not able to find with huge volume, although, I found with data sets in MBs but looking for GBs data sets.

If anyone has any idea about the data sets having **at-least 4 GBs** in size please share the links with me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Big Data is not just about volume. There are more criteria like variety, velocity and etc.

But recently, Forbes has published a post about 35 Big Data free datasets of 2016. You can check it out [here](http://www.forbes.com/sites/bernardmarr/2016/02/12/big-data-35-brilliant-and-free-data-sources-for-2016/#3b5ce2146796).

Comment: Thanks Mobin, It helped me a lot

Comment: Thanks, Mobob this helped a lot.

Answer (score -1):

The term big data means large amount of data. In a  present day   the number of people is increase .So  coresponding data is increaseing too. So handle this all data the term big data is came..The big data means not only structured data  it include all kind of data like semi structured unstructured.